# Bootstrap 4 Vertically align footer while respecting columns and rows

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to find a solution how to vertically align the 2 rows in the footer which are placed with a Bootstrap grid.

I've already tried to make a wrapper for the content and apply the regular flexbox solution:
display: flex; align-items: center. But this moves both rows to be on the same row.

Fiddle here https://codepen.io/pen/WNNPdxv

HTML

```
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8 footer-credit">
                        <h6>GetMove</h6>
                        <p>Copyright &copy 2019 GetMove All Rights Reserved</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 footer-contact">
                        <h6>Contact</h6>
                        <a href="hola@getmove.net">hola@getmove.net</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 footer-social-icons">
                        <h6>Follow us</h6>
                        <a class="social-icon" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/GetMove.Official/"
                            ><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i
                        ></a>
                        <a class="social-icon" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/getmovemx/"
                            ><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i
                        ></a>
                        <a class="social-icon" target="_blank" href="https://soundcloud.com/getmove"
                            ><i class="fab fa-soundcloud"></i
                        ></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8 text-center"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 footer-newsletter">
                        <h6>Subscribe</h6>
                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                class="form-control shadow-none"
                                id="subscribe"
                                placeholder="@ Enter your email adress"
                                aria-label="Sizing example input"
                                aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                            />
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1">
                                    Submit
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container footer-credit">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 footer-credit"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

CSS

```
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 24em; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    background-color: #f4f2f0;
    margin-top: 4em;
}

.footer-social-icons {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.footer h6 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.footer-credit {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.social-icon {
    /* display: block; */
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.form-control:focus {
    border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: vertically aligned how... in the centered in the entire footer? centered with each other? by `rows`, do you mean `containers` of which there are 3, (not 2) in the footer?

Comment: Can you draw the layout you want? You should minify your code and include only relevant parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of a wrapper to vertically center content is correct, however you already have a wrapper in place => `container`.
No need to have multiple containers inside a single section (footer). You use rows for this.

So to clean-up your structure a bit, as suggested in the comments, is key to understand what's going on.

- `container` is your wrapper
- `row row` is redundant
- empty columns as placeholder are not required with flexbox (bootstrap 4), not sure if that's what's going on... => `m-auto`, `ml-auto`, `mr-auto`
- place custom classes inside columns (these blocks might change places someday, especially when designing for a CMS)
- keep the structure clean and decorate with [utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/utilities-for-layout/) if needed (padding, margin, ...)

### HTML Structure

```
<footer role="contentinfo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5 ml-auto"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5 ml-auto"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

### Solution

Now your `height` is set on the footer, your container is simply taking the required height inside the space. This means you should now be able to move it vertically with flexbox.

```
footer[role="contentinfo"] {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center; /* content of the footer is the container */
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/L1fbjdku/)

Comment: Thank you Tim! This was a very helpful answer and it will improve my HTML structure for all future projects.